# Мониторинг HTTP запросов

Tags: http

Какими утилитами можно полностью отслеживать `HTTP` общение с неким сайтом, включая заголовки, `GET` и `POST` запросы - в общем ВСЁ что шлют друг другу браузер и сервер, в т.ч. если я нажимаю на какие-н. кнопки на сайте и т.п.

---

`CHROME Developer tools` не предлагать.

Comment: Первое что нашлось: HTTP Analyzer v5, наиболее правильным запросом будет «http sniffer», если эта программа Вам не подойдет.

Comment: http://fiddler2.com/ - на мой взгляд самый удобный, пользуюсь им. В отличии от HTTP Analyzer, бесплатен

Comment: ну и никто не отменял WireShark и WinDump (tcpDump), хотя это не очень удобно будет для этой задачи.

Comment: Charles самое то.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - прокси, который работает с трафиком между Вашим компьютером и удаленным сервером, и позволяет инспектировать и менять его.

Fiddler можно расширять с помощью скриптов на языке JScript.NET (писать их очень просто), кустомизировать меню программы, и вообще - замечательный инструмент.

Использовать его можно с любым браузером.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью Fiddler вы сможете отслеживать запросы только из браузера, так как Fiddler имитирует proxy server.

Если вы будете тестировать работу приложения, то вам необходимо будет настроить его на использование прокси Fiddler'а (`http://localhost:8888`), иначе ничего не увидите.

Так можно использовать другие sniffer'ы, например, [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).
Можно выбрать интерфейс и в "Capture filter..." прописать:

```
port 80 and src test.site.org
```

И wireshark будет отслеживать весь трафик по порту 80.
TCP пакеты можно скрыть, указав в "Apply display filter..." - http